# Hover effect not working correctly in google chrome

Tags: css, hover

I watched a video on Youtube about the hover effect, and I'm trying to do it by myself, but the problem is it's not working on google chrome: `:before` and `:after` background overflow when the transition executes.

In Firefox it works without any problem.
I thought it might be happening because I didn't use any prefixes, so I includes prefixes in code but the problem didn't go away

to be clear my problem
[background of :before and :after show out of button border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wBXZ.png)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

a {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition:color 1s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

a:before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 60px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: #F00;
  transform:scale(0.8);
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.8);
  border-radius:100%;
  -webkit-border-radius:100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity:0;
  transition-property:transform,left,opacity;
  transition-delay: 0s,1s,1.5s;
  transition-duration: 1s,1s,0s;
}

a:hover:before {
  border-radius:100%;
  -webkit-border-radius:100%;
  opacity:1;
  left: 10px;
  transform:scale(33);
  -webkit-transform:scale(33);
  transition-property:opacity,left,transform;
  transitiion-delay:0s,0.5s,2s;
  transition-duration: 0s,0.5s,1s;
}

a:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 60px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: #F00;
  transform:scale(0.8);
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.8);
  border-radius:100%;
  -webkit-border-radius:100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity:0;
  transition-property:transform,right,opacity;
  transition-delay: 0s,1s,1.5s;
  transition-duration: 1.5s,1s,0s;
}

a:hover:after {
  opacity:1;
  right: 10px;
  transform:scale(33);
  -webkit-transform:scale(33);
  transition-property:opacity,right,transform;
  transitiion-delay:0s,0.5s,2s;
  transition-duration: 0s,0.5s,1s;
}

a:hover{
  color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Button</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written `transitiion` instead of `transition` several times.

Your transition seems to be working (even if you do not say what you would like to do), it's just a little long.

You can play with the delay to change the duration of the animation, here is your code with shortened delays:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

a {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition:color .2s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .1s;
}

a:before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 60px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: #F00;
  transform:scale(0.8);
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.8);
  border-radius:100%;
  -webkit-border-radius:100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity:0;
  transition-property:transform,left,opacity;
  transition-delay: 0s,.5s,.5s;
  transition-duration: .5s,.5s,0s;
}

a:hover:before {
  border-radius:100%;
  -webkit-border-radius:100%;
  opacity:1;
  left: 10px;
  transform:scale(33);
  -webkit-transform:scale(33);
  transition-property:opacity,left,transform;
  transition-delay:0s,0.2s,.2s;
  transition-duration: 0s,0.2s,.2s;
}

a:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 60px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: #F00;
  transform:scale(0.8);
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.8);
  border-radius:100%;
  -webkit-border-radius:100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity:0;
  transition-property:transform,right,opacity;
  transition-delay: 0s,.2s,.2s;
  transition-duration: .2s,.2s,0s;
}

a:hover:after {
  opacity:1;
  right: 10px;
  transform:scale(33);
  -webkit-transform:scale(33);
  transition-property:opacity,right,transform;
  transition-delay:0s,0.2s,.2s;
  transition-duration: 0s,0.2s,.2s;
}

a:hover{
  color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Button</a>
```

Comment: my problem that's show out edges of <a> border image.ibb.co/eUQYv0/untitled-1.png not the transition itself

Comment: I don't see it in Chrome, are you sure your Chrome version is up to date?

Comment: Chrome version 67.0.3396.79

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your problem but if it is the absence of transition it could be because you have wrote transit**ii**on-delay instead of transition-delay.

I have tried your code with Chrome and Firefox and didn't noticed a difference.

You can learn more about the need (or absence of need) for prefixes on this website : https://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: my problem that's show out edges https://image.ibb.co/eUQYv0/untitled-1.png